# Why does merging with empty fs2.Stream change program's behavior

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fs2

It's well documented that merging with an empty `fs2.Stream` should produce the same `fs2.Stream`. Here is the quote from [Scaladocs](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/main/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/Stream.scala#L1882):

> Has the property that `merge(Stream.empty, s) == s`

Consider the following complete Scala program with `fs2.Stream`:

**Emitting elements**

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, IO, Timer}
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
import cats.effect.concurrent.Ref

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object TestFs2 extends App {
  implicit val timerIo: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)
  implicit val concurrentIo: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

  val program = Ref.of[IO, Int](0).map(ref => {
    fs2.Stream.repeatEval(ref.get).evalMap(value => {
      IO(println(s"Got value $value")) >> IO.sleep(1.second) >> ref.set(value + 1)
    })
  })

  program.flatMap(_.compile.drain).unsafeRunSync()
}
```

The program prints the following:

```
Got value 0
Got value 1
Got value 2
...
```

and it looks ok. Now applying the quote from `Scaladoc` above I concluded that replacing

```
fs2.Stream.repeatEval(ref.get)
```

with

```
fs2.Stream.repeatEval(ref.get).merge(fs2.Stream.empty.covaryAll[IO, Int])
```

the behavior should be the same. Here is the updated program:

**Emitting elements and merging with empty fs2.Stream**

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, IO, Timer}
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
import cats.effect.concurrent.Ref

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object TestFs2 extends App {
  implicit val timerIo: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)
  implicit val concurrentIo: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

  val program = Ref.of[IO, Int](0).map(ref => {
    fs2.Stream.repeatEval(ref.get).merge(fs2.Stream.empty.covaryAll[IO, Int]).evalMap(value => {
      IO(println(s"Got value $value")) >> IO.sleep(1.second) >> ref.set(value + 1)
    })
  })

  program.flatMap(_.compile.drain).unsafeRunSync()
}
```

The program output is

```
Got value 0
Got value 0
Got value 1
Got value 1
Got value 2
Got value 2
Got value 3
Got value 3
...
```

**QUESTION:** Why is merging with empty `fs2.Stream` changes the behavior of the program resulting in duplicating elements of the original `fs2.Stream`?

Comment: I guess this has something to do with `ref` rather than with `merge` or the _empty_ stream. It is true that the returned **Stream** is the same one as before. However, for some reason _(that I do not understand yet)_ the concurrent semantics of `get` changed. - In any case `get` + `set` as two different operations is not guaranteed to provide deterministic results as you have seen, you should be using `getAndUpdate` which does.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm not sure that `Ref` is the reason. In the original program I used `repeatEval` on extracting data from the database with doobie and got duplicated extraction. The bevahiour is not reproduced with `MVar` though... (upd: it's clear enough since `MVar` provides mutual exclusion access)

Comment: Again the problem is probably due concurrent semantics, not really `merge`. But I agree it is surprising enough to be frustrating. I would recommend you to ask in the [**gitter** channel](https://gitter.im/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) you would get quicker help there and you can come back and answer your own question here for future readers.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of `merge` also says:

> The implementation always tries to pull one chunk from each side before waiting for it to be consumed by resulting stream. As such, there may be up to two chunks (one from each stream) waiting to be processed while the resulting stream is processing elements.

If I understand this correctly that would mean that while the resulting stream is busy processing value `0`, a new value is already pulled from the source before `ref` has been updated.

Strictly speaking I don't think this behavior violates any invariants. But for you it makes a difference because

- your stream mutates the source from which it is pulling
- your source stream is *always* ready to emit an element

To solve the second point you could use a 1-element queue instead of a `Ref`.

AFAICT the same issue could occur without using `merge`. The stream is free to pull as many elements from the source as it sees fit before processing them, as long as the source can emit them. You basically got lucky in your first piece of code because you have a pretty simple stream with 1-element chunks.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a [bug](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/issues/1987).

[mpilquist](https://github.com/mpilquist) described the reason behind the behavior in the [comment](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/issues/1987#issuecomment-674092424) as

> It pulls the next chunk from the source stream and then acquires the
> semaphore permit, which is blocked until previous chunk is processed
> from the queue. Hence, it's always reading 1 chunk ahead.

Following **mpilquist**'s advices I created a [pull request](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/pull/1990) fixing the issue that was just merged.